# basic telegram bot example

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am recreating the basic telegram bot example from [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot2.py), but I am having a slight problem.

```py
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments bot and
# update. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hi!')

def help(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')

def echo(update, context):
    """Echo the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)

def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)

def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater("YOUR TOKEN HERE",use_context=True)
    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))
    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))
    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am getting below error after executing the script:

```
$ python test1.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "test1.py", line 39, in main
    updater = Updater(TOKEN,use_context=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that `use_context` is not a valid keyword argument for the Updater initializer. That argument is no longer supported in the 12th version of [Python Telegram Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot).

I guess you did `pip install python-telegram-bot==12.0.0b1 --upgrade` to install the library and it's installing the version 12.0.0b1.

You can do again the installation by running the following commnads:

1. Uninstall the current version of python-telegram-bot: `pip uninstall python-telegram-bot`
2. Install the 11 version of the library: `pip install python-telegram-bot==11`

Also, if you don't want to change your library version and keep using `python-telegram-bot` 12.0.0, you can just remove the `use_context` argument from the instantiation of the Updater class.

This line:

```
updater = Updater("YOUR TOKEN HERE",use_context=True)
```

Would become:

```
updater = Updater("YOUR TOKEN HERE")
```

Answer (score 1):

`use_context` is available as of version 12 of python-telegram-bot. You can find out the version you have installed via `pip show python-telegram-bot`.

The simplest solution would be to just remove the parameter `use_context`, i.e. replace

```py
updater = Updater("YOUR TOKEN HERE",use_context=True)
```

with

```py
updater = Updater("YOUR TOKEN HERE")
```